# Angle shape with only CSS

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JztOa.png)

I'm trying to achieve the shape via the picture attached, however I'm not going the right angles.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.angle {
  --offset: 30px;

  background: steelblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - var(--offset)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="angle"></div>
```

in the above snippet I used clip-path to cut a portion of the rectangle.
to learn more about it you can check the [**MDN web docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)